# Como destruir componente activex que esta gerando erro no delphi?

Tags: delphi, pdf, activex

Estou usando um componente ActiveX da Adobe PDF (TAcroPDF), funciona numa boa, acontece que ao fechar o formulário com as devidas linhas Release; FreeAndNil(TForm); no OnClose, ele ainda gera um erro ao fechar, me parece que não liberar da memoria o componente TAcroPDF pois em centenas de outros Forms na aplicação esse é o unico que tem esse componente e gera o erro, ao tirar o componente ele fecha normal.

Tentei dar um FreeAndNil(AcroPDF1); mas ele gera erro ao tentar destruir.

Ja tentei inúmeras formas de destruir o formulario e o objeto PDF mas sem sucesso, por isso vim até os colegas para ver se alguém pode dar alguma ideia do que mais posso fazer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A resposta para sua pergunta já foi respondida. Veja o link com a resposta.
[Erro ao fechar formulário com TAcroPDF no Delphi](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/286632/erro-ao-fechar-formul%C3%A1rio-com-tacropdf-no-delphi)

Answer (score 0):

Tenta fazer assim:

```
if(assigned(AcroPDF1)then 
  freeandNil(AcroPDF1)
```

ou

```
if(AcroPDF1 = nil)then 
      freeandNil(AcroPDF1)
```

O assigned faz o teste se o componente esta criado, se esta instanciado.
Pode ser que o componente ja esteja destuido, ou esteja em uso e ao destruir da erro.

Comment: Gabriel eu ja tinha tentando essas opções, o que acabei fazendo foi uma POG pra resolver o problema por enquanto assim:    **while (Assigned(AcroPDF)) do
 begin
  try
   AcroPDF.Free;
  finally
  end;
 end;**