# Erro ao fechar formulário com TAcroPDF no Delphi

Tags: delphi, formulário, pdf, componentes

Esse "bendito" componente, infelizmente preciso usá-lo, acontece que sempre que tento fechar o Form ele fecha, mas sempre dá um **AccessViolation**.

Não existe nada no Form além de um **TAcroPDF** e um botão Close.

A impressão que dá é que o formulário está sendo fechado antes de destruir o componente, acontece que já tentei usar `FreeAndNil(AcroPDF1); AcroPDF.Free; AcroPDF.Destroy` etc etc... e nada, ele insistem em dar o **AccessViolation**.

Coloquei a construção do Form dentro de um Try pra resolver o problema, mas não é a maneira correta, sempre que preciso mexer nesse Form em tempo de desenvolvimento, lá vem o maldito Accessviolation.

Alguém já passou por isso e conseguiu resolver?

Obs: Resolvi esse problema em outra tela usando o TWebbrowser para abrir PDF, mas uso esse TAcroPDF em varias telas e teria que reescreve-las podendo gerar outros problemas na aplicação já que esse TWebbrowser também é um componente chato de mexer, antes de partir pro radical gostaria de saber se existe uma solução mais amigável para o TAcroPDF.

Comment: Marcelo, já tentou colocar o FreeAndNil(AcroPDF1); no "FormClose"? Consegue detectar em qual linha ele dá o Access Violation?

Esse erro pode estar associado também ao src ainda estar instanciado no momento do fechamento. Tente dar um ``AcroPdf1.Src := ''`` antes do FreeAndNil pra ver se resolve.

Comment: Ja dei um FreeAndNil, Destroy, Free... em todas elas da erro, me parece que ele não deixa destruir dessa forma, o AcroPDF.Src := '' ainda não tentei, vou ver se funciona. Com debug e manda para Units que não tem nada a ver com o componente nem o Form em questão, como é um ActiveX parece que ele trabalha paralelamente, o isso dificulta o debug.

Comment: Dá uma olhada se o ``AcroPdf1.Src := ''`` antes do Free ajuda. Fico no aguardo do seu retorno! Se não for, procuro mais alguma forma de simular esse erro.

Comment: Tentei colocar o src := '', mas o erro continua, fiz uma aplicação teste bem simples so com o componente AcroPDF e o erro persiste, se quiser baixar segue o link: http://mvsoftware.com.br/downloads/AcroPDF.rar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A destruição deveria ocorrer assim que o `Form` invoca o `Destroy` dos seus "filhos".

O que acontece nesse caso é que um de seus filhos não é um objeto instanciado e sim inicializado, o que ocorre normalmente em alguns componentes ActiveX.

Em alguns casos resolve-se apenas incluindo no `Create` do Form um `CoInitialize` que irá instanciar todos os Objetos ActiveX, e no `Close` acionar o `CoUnitialize` que por sua vez removera da interface todos os ActoveX.

No caso do AcroPdf, ele não é um objeto que possa ser destruído junto da interface, então, precisamos avisa-lo que ele precisa se destruir.

Encontrei no SOEn uma solução que por incrível que pareça funciona a muito tempo.

No close:

```
AcroPdf1.ControlInterface._AddRef;
```

Dessa forma ele vai invocar o `_Release` do componente, não adianta invocar o _Release diretamente, existem processos internos da aplicação que devem ser realizados para o feito, tais como sua própria liberação de memória alocada.

Não é culpa de sua Aplicação e nem do componente, a culpa é do próprio Delphi que permite que objetos sejam criados sem uma criação de Classe bem feita.
Digo, existe um `Construtor` e não Existe um `Destructor`.

Vale lembrar que este componente em VB.6 isto não ocorre com tanta frequência.

[Pergunta com semelhança.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37885850/acrobat-reader-activex-access-violation-on-form-close)

Comment: Caramba, não é que funciona mesmo, rsrs, valeu Júnior, quando eu ia imaginar que existe AcroPdf1.ControlInterface._AddRef; pra ajudar o ActiveX desgarrar da memória, rsrsrs